# Is there a PouchDB / CouchDB equivalent for MySQL's percentage sign

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

Is there a equivalent sign for the MySQL's percentage sign

```
Character | Description
----------+-------------------------------------------------------
    %     | Matches any number of characters, even zero characters
```

I want to do something similar like

```
%john%
```

which should get any ID similar to.

```
john_doe
doe_john
john_smith
smith_john
etc.
```

Startkey & Endkey is not delivering the needed result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent, no. But the `pouchdb-find` plugin ([try it here](http://nolanlawson.github.io/pouchdb-find/)) will have a `$regex` option when it is finished.

In the meantime, you can do prefix searching (e.g. `'john%'`) [as described here](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-quick-search#autosuggestions-and-prefix-search). Note that suffix searching (e.g. `'%john'`) is super slow in any database, because of how B-trees work.

Comment: Thanks for answering, the pouchdb-find plugin helped me solve the issue.. since I had implemented secondary IDs as doc fields for future usage this plugin actually came in handy.